# Does ECMAScript 2015(ECMAScript 6) have class initializer?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I've looked in ECMAScript 2015 recently.
Does ECMAScript 2015 have class initializer?

For example, I tried to write class like a parser;

```
class URLParser {
    parse(url) {
        let regex = /(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\?]*)\?([^#]*)#(.*)/;
        (....)
    }
}

var a = new URLParser();
a.parse('http://example.com/abc');
a.parse('http://example.com/def');
var b = new URLParser();
b.parse('https://sample.net/abc');
b.parse('https://sample.net/def');
```

This regex is **common in class**, so I'd like to initialize it only once.
I know to use constructor for reduction of initializing, but affects **instance wide**.
I'd like to know how to reduct initializing **class wide**.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean a constructor??

Comment: @Amit" *"I know to use constructor for reduction of initializing, but affects instance wide."*

Comment: @FelixKling - yes you're right. I really had a hard time reading the question ;-)

Comment: wouldnt you want to call your super class in this scenario and use `extend`?

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

I see ECMAScript 2015 have no class-level declarative initialization, So there are some other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. [There is a proposal for static properties though](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties).

Until then, as always, you can add shared properties to the prototype:

```
URLParser.prototype.regex = /(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\?]*)\?([^#]*)#(.*)/;
```

and access it inside your method via `this.regex`.

Comment: but this is also related to instance objects, to affect the whole class it would be `URLParser.regex = /(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\?]*)\?([^#]*)#(.*)/;`.

Comment: *"this is also related to instance objects"* I guess. But it's only executed once. In the end it depends on how you want to access the value. `URLParser.regex` vs `this.regex`.

Comment: based on this statement _I know to use constructor for reduction of initializing, but affects **instance wide**_ I guess that he wants to use it like a static property `URLParser.regex`

Comment: Maybe. The constructor only applies to a single instance though (i.e. every instance has a copy of the data). So there is still a difference between adding something in the constructor and adding something to the prototype. My solution solves the *"This regex is common in class, so I'd like to initialize it only once."* part. It can't be bad to have multiple options :)

Comment: Also, I don't know what the OP's definitions of "instance wide" and "class wide" are.

Comment: The `.prototype` solution seems more idiomatic in JS as well.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment is not possible to create static properties in ES6 classes, but only static methods.

---

But you can attach properties directly to the class, which will emulate static properties:

```
class URLParser {
    parse(url) {
        URLParser.regex.match(...);
        (....)
    }
}
URLParser.regex = /(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\?]*)\?([^#]*)#(.*)/;
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not. There is a proposal for class-level declarative initialization, so you could potentially do

```
class URLParser {
    static regex = /(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\?]*)\?([^#]*)#(.*)/;
}
```

and then use `URLParser.regex` everywhere to access it. A better, less verbose, approach would be to take advantage of JS scoping and just put the regex before the class. There's nothing to gain by having the regex attached to the class.

```
let regex = /(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\?]*)\?([^#]*)#(.*)/;

class URLParser {
  parse(url) {
    (....)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to make `static` properties in JavaScript, however, you could just define the property in the `constructor`

```
class URLParser {
    constructor() {
        this.regex = /(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\?]*)\?([^#]*)#(.*)/;
    }
    parse(url) {
        this.regex.match(url)
        (...);
    }
}
```